# fstab wrong uuid and server in emergency mode

Tags: ubuntu, fstab, ubuntu-22.04

I copied from an old server setup to `fstab` (unsure now why I did so), and with it I overwrote the correct uuid. When I rebooted the server it started in emergency mode and I suspect the reason is that I have wrong specs in `fstab`.

How can I modify the correct uuid into `fstab` while its unwritable?
With `blkid` I get the correct uuid and it's found in `fstab` but commented out.

tried running

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount: /: can't find UUID=old server uuid
```

Comment: Why is it unwritable? Is the filesystem mounted readonly? (ro flag)

Comment: Because the server is in emergency mode, or I presume that is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Boot server
startup menu, press e for edit, Line starting with Linux= switch ro to rw and add word single at the very end of the line, press f10 for reboot. Go to fstab and correct issues.

This fixed fstab and other system files being unwritable. Hope this helps someone else too

Answer (score 0):

On your command: `mount -o remount,rw /` you are not specifying the device. For that reason, the system is looking for `/etc/fstab` (to see what device is your default for /).

You say you have the new UUID from blkid, then you can use the command: `mount -U <NEWUUID> /`

Otherwise it will keep trying to mount the UUID in fstab. Once you can write fstab, you can set the new UUID.